# Elastic search: calculate duration / session length from timestamps (first seen and last seen)

Tags: session, elasticsearch, timestamp, duration, kibana

I could't find anything using Google.
Therefore I hope you could help me here:

Imagine the following data:

```
{ timestamp: 123, id: abcd }, 
{ timestamp: 234, id: abcd }, 
{ timestamp: 543, id: abcd }
{ timestamp: 673, id: abcd }
```

I want to calculate the session length from this data in elastic search / kibana.
A session is continuous, if the timestamp interval between two ordered entries is e.g. smaller than 200. According to the above data, two sessions should be created:

```
1: 234-123 = 111 < 200 | session 1, duration 111
2: 543-234 = 311 > 200 | session 2, duration ...
3: 673-543 = 130 < 200 | session 2, duration 130
```

How can I achieve that in elastic search?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you write a script that does that calculation for you, once you retrieved all the needed data from ES?

Comment: The underlying database is Couchbase. Every entry gets replicated to Elasticsearch immediately. I try to solve this problem by doing the session calculation / abstraction with a separate script outside of Couchbase and save the result in Couchbase again in order to replicate it directly to Elasticsearch and work with it.